# capybara testing unable to sign in

Tags: authentication, capybara

```
describe "create post", :js => true do
  before :each do
  a = User.create!(:email => 'any@gmail.com', :password => 'admin123', :password_confirmation => 'admin123', :firstname => "black")
  a.confirm!
end

it "signs me in" do

  get root_path
  visit '/'
   within(".form-inline") do
     fill_in 'Email', :with => 'any@gmail.com'
     fill_in 'Password', :with => 'admin123'        
   end
   click_button 'Sign in'

    save_and_open_page
  end
 end
```

when i execute with rake spec:requests

i'm unable to login, i'm getting invalid email or password error in browser.
please tell me what to do?

Comment: Does it work with credentials of existing users, not newly created one?